# Loading my javascript file - issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

So been looking into other similar issues on the site, and none have helped so far, although I'm certain my issue is trivial as I'm only just starting out with javascript.

I initially created the script directly in the HTML file. This ran fine and produced the results I expected.
I have now tried to separate it into a file that I want to load into HTML.

In the body of my HTML doc I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='dash.js') }}"></script>
```

Which should load the file below.

As I mentioned, the "applySettings" code is what I know works from my previous tests which it was directly in the HTML file. The rest I added to try and make the file work.

**dash.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

alert("READY!");
applySettings();
});

function applySettings(){
    $("#example").dataTable({
        "aaData":[
        ["Sitepoint","http://sitepoint.com","Blog","2013-10-15 10:30:00"],
        ["Flippa","http://flippa.com","Marketplace","null"],
        ["99designs","http://99designs.com","Marketplace","null"],
        ["Learnable","http://learnable.com","Online courses","null"],
        ["Rubysource","http://rubysource.com","Blog","2013-01-10 12:00:00"]
    ],

    "aoColumnDefs":[{
    "sTitle":"Site name"
    "aTargets": [ "site_name" ]
    },{

        "aTargets": [ 1 ]
        "bSortable": false
        "mRender": function ( url, type, full )  {
            return  '<a href="'+url+'">' + url + '</a>';
        }
    },{

        "aTargets":[ 3 ]
        , "sType": "date"
        , "mRender": function(date, type, full) {
             return (full[2] == "Blog") 
             ? new Date(date).toDateString()
             : "N/A" ;
            }

    }],
    'paging': false,
    'searching': false,
    'lengthChange': false,
    'info': false,
    'destroy': true,                
});
}
```

when I run the app (as this is though pythons flask addin). I can see my terminal output the below which suggests it's reaching out for the file in the location I expect, but not even the alert in the javascript appears when I refresh the webpage:

```
2017-02-24 08:56:30,503 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2017 08:56:30] "GET /static/jquery-1.12.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-02-24 08:56:30,506 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2017 08:56:30] "GET /static/jquery.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2017-02-24 08:56:30,510 INFO  127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2017 08:56:30] "GET /static/dash.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output to ensure the file path is correct? Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: Wel I'm running this through the python flask imports. but while it's running, in terminal, i can see it reach out for the file in the location and everything looks correct in that regard. will add the info of what shows when I run it to the main info.

Comment: Put an `alert` outside any function code (eg as the very first line of the file) so it executes immediately on load.  No alert = file not loading.  Alert = file load, no 2nd alert (in jquery startup) = jquery not loaded yet (or at all)

Comment: Just tried this. put:  alert("In the file!")  in the first line of the file and nothing worked. Also removed the type and charset as advised Irfan, but that didn't work.